# Cast a simple (c++) struct to another derived (c++) struct containing same datatypes

Tags: c++, class, memory-management, struct, casting

**Hello everyone,**

I have a simple struct C which contains 3 variables.
Then I have two structs, A and B, where B is derived from A. All in all, B contains the same 3 types of variables as in my simple struct C.

(Note: C++ structs are used)

**My questions:**

1. Can I cast between C and B as in my example below, i.e. is it allowed
   or do I have to look at something special (memory)? My example below
   produces no valgrind mem error. However, I want to be sure what you 
   think about it.
2. Am I right, that if B inherits from A, the variables from struct A are
   put before (or afterwards - depending on architecture) the variables
   of B in memory, i.e. do I have everytime an "ordered" memory which 
   fits to struct C ordering/memory? Or can it
   happen, that e.g. the "type" variable from A is between the "str" and
   "value" variable?

Hope you can help me! Thanks in advance.

**Example (C++11 style):**

```
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

struct a
{
    unsigned int type;

    a(unsigned int t) : type(t)
    {}
};

struct b : public a
{
    std::string str;
    unsigned int value;

    b() : a(2), str("Hello"), value(1)
    {}
};

struct c
{
    unsigned int type;

    std::string str;
    unsigned int value;

    c() : type(1), str("World"), value(42)
    {};
};

int main(int argc, char*argv[])
{
    // Bottom up
    {
        std::cout << "Bottom Up" << std::endl;

        c* ptr2 = new c();

        std::cout << ptr2->type << std::endl;
        std::cout << ptr2->str << std::endl;
        std::cout << ptr2->value << std::endl;

        std::shared_ptr<b>ptr;
        ptr.reset(reinterpret_cast<b*>(ptr2));

        std::cout << ptr->type << std::endl;
        std::cout << ptr->str << std::endl;
        std::cout << ptr->value << std::endl;
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    // Top down
    {
        std::cout << "Top down" << std::endl;
        std::shared_ptr<b>ptr(new b());

        std::cout << ptr->type << std::endl;
        std::cout << ptr->str << std::endl;
        std::cout << ptr->value << std::endl;

        c* ptr2 = reinterpret_cast<c*>(ptr.get());

        std::cout << ptr2->type << std::endl;
        std::cout << ptr2->str << std::endl;
        std::cout << ptr2->value << std::endl;
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If all of the structs are POD (see above link) then it would be safe(r) to do this, but the second they aren't, this is undefined behavior. For example you have inheritance (and therefore a v-table), user defined constructors, non-POD members, etc. So your example will not work.

Comment: The classes in the example are not virtual, so there are no v-tables.

Comment: Hello, yes in my case, I do *not* have any virtual functions. - Thanks for that Link!